# String pattern matching - match particular text in a line

Tags: java, regex

I need to match a String and retrieve data from it using Java.

e.g.

String `line='Id 878-234` provide info for the number 878-234

Following are the expected results:

1. I want to match for "Id", and need to pull the six digit no.
2. Id should be positioned at the beginning of the line.
3. If id is not available at beginning of line it should search for six digit not separated by `-`.

   ```
   String text='Id 878-234 provide info for 1233444 no';
   String regex='^Id ([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3})';

   Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

   if(m.matches()) 
   {

                   System.debug(m.group(1));
   }
   ```

I am using above code but it is not working. please let me no how to solve this bcz i am new to regular expression.

Comment: Have you tried searching around for various solutions? This isn't an uncommon problem, and has likely been answered on SO dozens of times...

Comment: To be honest I didn't get your question.

Comment: However I edited it, but still I didn't get your question exactly. What does this thing mean?  provide info for 1233444 no?

Comment: 123344 is just another digit which i need to ignore it

Comment: I am not able to pull "878-234" digit for line. Provide me example to solve this problem

Comment: Where are you stuck? Seems like a regex, or even a simple if\else flow if it's for a starter Java course (which I'm assuming it is) should do the trick.

Comment: Please find my above code i have updated the question

Comment: Better, but can you add more detail to "it is not working"? We can't read your mind.

Comment: That doesn't help. *How* is it not working? What do you get?

Comment: @JayantJadhav your command works for me.See http://ideone.com/y0cvOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below regex would get the 6 digit number separated by `-` which was just after to the string ID,

```
String s = "Id 878-234 provide info for 1233444 no";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^Id\\s*([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group(1));
} //=> 878-234
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/SYdpnA)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`m.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) Instead of [`m.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29).

*According to Java Doc*

- matches will return true *if and only if* the entire region or `String` matches this pattern while
- find tries to **FIND** next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String line="Id 878-234 provide info for 1233444 no";
    String[] ints = line.split("[^0-9]+");
    int a1 = Integer.parseInt(ints[1]);
    int a2 = Integer.parseInt(ints[2]);
    int a3 = Integer.parseInt(ints[3]);
    System.out.println(a1);
    System.out.println(a2);
    System.out.println(a3);
    output:
    878
    234
    1233444
```